# convert another timezone time to local time in momentjs

Tags: momentjs

I want to convert Fiji(Pacific/Fiji) time to my local time.

suppose, 
I have Fiji(Pacific/Fiji) time "Thu, 10 November 2016 03:47" PM and I am in India then convert it in India(Asia/Kolkata) time "Thu, 10 November 2016 08:17 AM".

so, question is
which time string need for Fiji? and how to convert it to local time in moment.js?

Answer (score 0):

need to UTC string like `2016-11-16T06:30:00.000Z`

working fiddel here:

http://jsfiddle.net/d06047c5/